# Strange behavior of python socket in docker container

Tags: python, sockets, docker, udp

I observed a behavior of my python code running in a docker container I don't understand. Maybe someone can explain me the behavior and can me tell the difference between python socket on *Ubuntu 18.04* and the docker image *python:3.6*

If I start my UDP socket at my host the server thread unblock on every received datagram and print the bytes out. That is the behavior I expect.

If I start the same code in docker container, there is no unblocking and no output to stdout. If a stop the server with ctrl+c the output is printed before the interrupt exception.

**UPDATE**

- Add a example for a thread printing out to stdout without any
  problems. See I/O Test.
- Add code to show the the ininstantiating of the objects and the
  start() call.
- Add Docker run commands. Start the container and print out stdout.
- Remove unnecessary print() output.

Thanks and enjoy my creepy code!

**Dockerfile: Server**

```
FROM python:3.6

COPY . /workdir
EXPOSE 8888
WORKDIR /workdir
CMD ["./main.py"]
```

**Dockerfile: I/O Test**

```
FROM python:3.6

COPY . /workdir
EXPOSE 8888
WORKDIR /workdir
CMD ["./iotest.py"]
```

**I/O test (same as UDPServer but without blocking socket) ***

```
import threading

    class iotest(threading.Thread):

        def __init__(self):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        def run(self):
            print("Server Thread started!")
            try:
                while True:
                    print("Test i/o")
            except Exception as e:
                print("Exception catched")
                print(e)
            finally:
                print("Thread exited")
```

**Server:**

```
import threading
import socket


class UDPServer(threading.Thread):
    PORT = 8888
    HOST = '0.0.0.0'

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print("Server Thread started!")
        try:
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
            s.bind((UDPServer.HOST, UDPServer.PORT))
            while True:
                msg = s.recv(4)
                print("Message received")
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception catched")
            print(e)
        finally:
            print("Thread exited, Socket closed")
            s.close()
```

**I/O test (same as UDPServer but without blocking socket) ***

```
import threading

    class iotest(threading.Thread):

        def __init__(self):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        def run(self):
            print("Server Thread started!")
            try:
                while True:
                    print("Test i/o")
            except Exception as e:
                print("Exception catched")
                print(e)
            finally:
                print("Thread exited")
```

**Client:**

```
import socket
import time

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(('0.0.0.0', 8888))
count = 0
errors = 0
for i in range(10):
    isTime = time.time()
    msg = struct.pack('!f', isTime, )
    time.sleep(0.5)
    try:
        size_date_sent = s.send(msg)
        count += 1
    except Exception as identifier:
        errors += 1

print(str(count) + " MSG sent.")
print(str(errors) + " errors.")
s.close()
```

**main.py:**

```
import UDPServer

server = UDPServer.UDPServer()
server.start()
```

**iotest.py**

```
import iotest

thr = iotest.iotest()
thr.start
```

**Build and run**

```
docker build -t pythontest .
docker run -p 8888:8888/udp pythontest
```

Comment: First problem is that your output is being buffered when you run the program inside docker because its output is not directed to a terminal device. Change your last Dockerfile line to `CMD ["python", "-u", "./main.py"]` (run with standard I/O unbuffered)

Comment: For any other problems you have, please post a [mcve]. Your server class given above isn't even instantiated anywhere. So a reader has to guess what exactly you're doing. Provide main.py. Also, provide your `docker run` command too as that will affect how the networking operates within your container.

Comment: Hi I updated my problem description and my code. The solution from @GilHamilton with the "-u" parameter works but I don't understand why. The I/O Test print out to stdout without this parameter!

Comment: @MarLei were you able to solve this issue? I have the exact same problem, which only occurs when I run docker without creating a custom network!