# Polling Socket Select inside Docker on Windows (via Python/Pyramid)

Tags: python-3.x, docker, sockets, pyramid

tl;dr - Example code from Pyramid cookie cutter example does not respond to requests generated from outside the hosting Docker container on Windows. Other code that doesn't rely on non-blocking I/O (socket select) seems to work as expected.

References:

- https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tutorial/cookiecutters.html
- https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid-cookiecutter-starter

I am trying to work through some of the example code for using Pyramid (the Python-based web development framework). I am doing this from inside a Docker container (3.6.9-Buster) on Windows 10. Should be simple, at least for running some sample code, right?

It has, predictably, been a nightmare.

The example code just will not work. Problems with lack of IPv6 support choking the code that presumes/requires it, and so on.

Currently, I have the test server from the cookie-cutter-starter running and binding to the port successfully, but it never responds to requests from outside the container.

As background, I haven't touched web development in over 15 years, and avoid Python as much as possible (which is impossible these days), so I could be missing something obvious.

Now, I definitely have the port forwarding enabled properly. I was able to bring up a different HTTP server in the container (also written in Python) on the same port successfully and communicate with it from outside the container. In the case of the example I am working on, however, I only seem to be able to get it to respond to a connection if I spawn another thread inside the Python process and connect from there.

The embedded cookie cutter server, waitress (I think that's the name, it has a ton of unnecessary redirection and wrappers and superfluous classes, so its hard to be sure what is what), is using non-blocking I/O. Where it calls the socket select during polling is apparently where the problem occurs. The select never returns a connection initiated from the outside.

I haven't found any kind of firewall issues. And, as I said, I am able to communicate with other Python code executed from within the container, so I don't think there is anything wrong with the system configuration in that regard. This seems specific to the socket select and non-blocking I/O, which appears to be the main difference between the server implementations.

```py
#From within env/lib/python-3.6/site-packages/waitress/wasyncore.py:
def poll(timeout=0.0, map=None):
    if map is None: # pragma: no cover
        map = socket_map
    if map:
        r = []; w = []; e = []
        for fd, obj in list(map.items()): # list() call FBO py3
            is_r = obj.readable()
            is_w = obj.writable()
            if is_r:
                r.append(fd)
            # accepting sockets should not be writable
            if is_w and not obj.accepting:
                w.append(fd)
            if is_r or is_w:
                e.append(fd)
        if [] == r == w == e:
            time.sleep(timeout)
            return

        try:
            #Attention StackOverflow: Note the print statements here.
            print("\n select(r=", r, ", w=", w, ", e=", e, ")\n")
            r, w, e = select.select(r, w, e, timeout)
            print(" r=", r, " w=", w, " e=", e, " = select(...)\n")
        except select.error as err:
            if err.args[0] != EINTR:
                raise
            else:
                return
        for fd in r:
            obj = map.get(fd)
            if obj is None: # pragma: no cover
                continue
            read(obj)

        for fd in w:
            obj = map.get(fd)
            if obj is None: # pragma: no cover
                continue
            write(obj)

        for fd in e:
            obj = map.get(fd)
            if obj is None: # pragma: no cover
                continue
            _exception(obj)
```

Expected (also, results when connecting from another thread within the container):

> select(r= [5, 6] , w= [] , e= [5, 6] )
>
> r= [6]  w= []  e= []  = select(...)
>
> select(r= [5, 6, 8] , w= [] , e= [5, 6, 8] )
>
> r= [8]  w= []  e= []  = select(...)
>
> select(r= [5, 6] , w= [8] ,  e= [5, 6, 8] )
>
> r= [5]  w= [8]  e= []  = select(...)
>
> select(r= [5, 6] , w= [] , e= [5, 6] )
>
> r= []  w= []  e= []  = select(...)

Actual:

> select(r= [5, 6] , w= []  e= [5, 6] )
>
> r= []  w= []  e= []  = select(...)

Is this a known bug? Is non-blocking I/O not supported by Docker on Windows? Is there some other complicating factor that might cause select to come up empty every time?

My best guess is that somewhere in the path from the Windows kernel through the Docker layer, the flag for the select is getting lost, and it never propagates up to the Python code.

All I can do from here, I think, is to test the socket library in isolation and perhaps test the system calls from C. If I understand correctly, Python is just passing through to the system calls anyway. In any case, that won't necessarily isolate the cause of problem, nor does it seem to offer hope of a solution.

At this point, I am on the verge of just scrapping all projects that would depend on this sort of thing, because they may not be worth the hassle. If canned example code is this much trouble, it perhaps doesn't seem worth using as a platform. Just run away as fast as I can? Is it just going to be one problem after another, until I re-write the whole stack myself? Am I almost to the point where I can start doing what I originally set out to do (programming a web interface)?

EDIT: Thanks for the reply. I may not continue with this, since it's such a hassle. For completeness, I'm adding the suggested information and will leave this open for a day or two, then I may close it. As requested, here's the development.ini section:

```
[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
listen = 0.0.0.0:6543
```

And here is the command used to start the container:

> docker run -t -p 6543:6543 --mount src=".",target=/scratch,type=bind --interactive pyramid_hello_world

Hopefully it is useful to someone.

Comment: FWIW, I can run a Pyramid application either outside or inside of a Docker container and it will respond to requests on macOS. I would suggest that you first try to run the Pyramid app outside of a container to ensure that it works. Then containerize it. Also provide your `development.ini`'s `[server:main] listen` section and value, your configuration for how you expose the port, as well as the command you use to start the container, by editing your question. Docker uses `0.0.0.0`, not `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Looks like the same problem at https://stackoverflow.com/q/54990469/1709894, that may help. Now I just have to find a way to fix it in my C++ code :)